# How to convert a string of numbers to an array of numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have below string -

```
var a = "1,2,3,4";
```

when I do -

```
var b = a.split(',');
```

I get `b` as `["1", "2", "3", "4"]`

can I do something to get `b` as `[1, 2, 3, 4]` ?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

My 2 cents for golfers:

```
b="1,2,3,4".split`,`.map(x=>+x)
```

backquote is string litteral so we can omit the parenthesis (because of the nature of split function) but it is equivalent to `split(',')`. The string is now an array, we just have to map each value with a function returning the integer of the string so `x=>+x` (which is even shorter than the `Number` function (5 chars instead of 6)) is equivalent to :

```
function(x){return parseInt(x,10)}// version from techfoobar
(x)=>{return parseInt(x)}         // lambda are shorter and parseInt default is 10
(x)=>{return +x}                  // diff. with parseInt in SO but + is better in this case
x=>+x                             // no multiple args, just 1 function call
```

I hope it is a bit more clear.

Comment: why does this work like this?  Seems non-elegant because it's too abstracted.

Comment: Why would we care about how many chars the map function uses?

Comment: Odd, in angular 7 the parenthesis are required.

Comment: @SafeFastExpressive because this is a version for "golfers", if you don't know what I am talking about : https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Clever, but I'd kick a colleague if they included something like this in real code.

Comment: the back ticks pattern similar to react style components....

Comment: @SafeFastExpressive You probably don't know what code golf is

Answer (score 547):

You can use `Array.map` to convert each element into a number.

```
var a = "1,2,3,4";

var b = a.split(',').map(function(item) {
    return parseInt(item, 10);
});
```

Check the [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

---

Or more elegantly as pointed out by User: thg435

```
var b = a.split(',').map(Number);
```

Where `Number()` would do the rest:check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

---

**Note:** For older browsers that don't support `map`, you can add an implementation yourself like:

```
Array.prototype.map = Array.prototype.map || function(_x) {
    for(var o=[], i=0; i<this.length; i++) { 
        o[i] = _x(this[i]); 
    }
    return o;
};
```

Comment: The ["Tricky use case"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Tricky_use_case) in the documentation actually talks about this subject.

Comment: Note: make sure you check the browser version in that link, IE8 does not support Array.map. (Surprising, eh?)

Comment: To convert string to array of digits, use empty string as delimeter: `'1234567'.split('').map(Number);`

Comment: I've started doing:

`items.length > 0 ?  items.split(',').map(Number) : []`

to ensure I don't have an empty string array.

Comment: Worth noting that Number() won't force integers, only numbers. If you need to cast specifically to ints, use parseInt(). `"1.1,2,3".split(",").map(Number)` is `[1.1, 2, 3]` whereas `"1.1,2,3".split(",").map(item => parseInt(item, 10))` is `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: @techfoobar Can you pls tell me what is happening here.why pass 10 ? `return parseInt(item, 10);`

Comment: @Sachith - The second argument to parseInt() is the base. In this case 10. 
Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: IMHO this is the most correct answer because parseInt is the correct way to convert a string over to a number.  I am assuming .map(Number) would be second and I don't even know what .map(x=>+x) is actually doing behind the scenes to make that work

Answer (score 60):

> This is very simple.Such as:

```js
["1", "2", "3", "4"].map(i=>Number(i))
```

you can run the demo.

```js
let result = ["1", "2", "3", "4"].map(i=>Number(i));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Or simply: `.map(Number)`

Comment: That is not correct. He said he has a string of numbers, not an array of strings. os this will not work. you need to use split(',') before the map(Number).

Answer (score 29):

1. `.map(Number)`.

   ```js
   let c = ["1", "2", "3", "4"].map(Number); // 2x as performant. See benchmark
   ```
2. `Array.from()` for details go to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

   ```js
   let a = "1,2,3,4";
   let b = Array.from(a.split(','),Number);
   ```

`b` and `c` is an array of numbers.

#### Demonstration:

```js
let a = "1,2,3,4";
let b = Array.from(a.split(','),Number);

let c = ["1", "2", "3", "4"].map(Number);

console.log(`b: ${b}, c: ${c}`);
```

#### Benchmarks

[image]

Comment: This is the most straightforward way I found!!

Comment: Both seem good. Would love to see a benchmark on both of these methods to help decide which one to use.

Comment: Okay, I ran some benchmarks to compare them and there is a clear winner. `array.map( Number )` is about twice as fast as using `Array.from( array, Number )`. I'll add a summary image to the answer.

Answer (score 19):

Map it to integers:

```
a.split(',').map(function(i){
    return parseInt(i, 10);
})
```

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) looks at every array item, passes it to the function provided and returns an array with the return values of that function. `map` isn't available in old browsers, but most libraries like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#map) include a cross-browser version.

Or, if you prefer loops:

```
var res = a.split(",");
for (var i=0; i<res.length; i++)
{
    res[i] = parseInt(res[i], 10);
}
```

Answer (score 18):

A more shorter solution: map and pass the arguments to `Number`:

```js
var a = "1,2,3,4";
var b = a.split(',');
console.log(b);
var c = b.map(Number);
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 17):

`+string` will try to change the string to a number. Then use `Array.map` function to change every element.

```
"1,2,3,4".split(',').map(function(el){ return +el;});
```

Comment: Or could be simpler `"1,2,3,4".split(',').map((el) => +el)`

Answer (score 10):

One liner

```
Array.from(a.split(','), Number)
```

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to use lambdas and/or give `radix` parameter to `parseInt`, just use `parseFloat` or `Number` instead.

**Reasons:**

1. It's working:

   ```
   var src = "1,2,5,4,3";
   var ids = src.split(',').map(parseFloat); // [1, 2, 5, 4, 3]

   var obj = {1: ..., 3: ..., 4: ..., 7: ...};
   var keys= Object.keys(obj); // ["1", "3", "4", "7"]
   var ids = keys.map(parseFloat); // [1, 3, 4, 7]

   var arr = ["1", 5, "7", 11];
   var ints= arr.map(parseFloat); // [1, 5, 7, 11]
   ints[1] === "5" // false
   ints[1] === 5   // true
   ints[2] === "7" // false
   ints[2] === 7   // true
   ```
2. It's shorter.
3. It's a tiny bit quickier and *takes advantage of cache, when `parseInt`-approach - doesn't*:

   ```
     // execution time measure function
     // keep it simple, yeah?
   > var f = (function (arr, c, n, m) {
         var i,t,m,s=n();
         for(i=0;i++<c;)t=arr.map(m);
         return n()-s
     }).bind(null, "2,4,6,8,0,9,7,5,3,1".split(','), 1000000, Date.now);

   > f(Number) // first launch, just warming-up cache
   > 3971 // nice =)

   > f(Number)
   > 3964 // still the same

   > f(function(e){return+e})
   > 5132 // yup, just little bit slower

   > f(function(e){return+e})
   > 5112 // second run... and ok.

   > f(parseFloat)
   > 3727 // little bit quicker than .map(Number)

   > f(parseFloat)
   > 3737 // all ok

   > f(function(e){return parseInt(e,10)})
   > 21852 // awww, how adorable...

   > f(function(e){return parseInt(e)})
   > 22928 // maybe, without '10'?.. nope.

   > f(function(e){return parseInt(e)})
   > 22769 // second run... and nothing changes.

   > f(Number)
   > 3873 // and again
   > f(parseFloat)
   > 3583 // and again
   > f(function(e){return+e})
   > 4967 // and again

   > f(function(e){return parseInt(e,10)})
   > 21649 // dammit 'parseInt'! >_<
   ```

*Notice: In Firefox `parseInt` works about 4 times faster, but still slower than others. In total: `+e` < `Number` < `parseFloat` < `parseInt`*

Answer (score 5):

Use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) for this, Try this:

```js
let b = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
b = Array.from(b,Number);
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 4):

As a variant you can use combiantion `_.map` and `_.ary` methods from the [lodash library](https://lodash.com). Whole transformation will be a more compact. Here is example from the [official documentation](https://lodash.com/docs#ary):

```
_.map(['6', '8', '10'], _.ary(parseInt, 1));
// → [6, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 4):

This works amazing if you need to convert an array of strings to numbers.

```
const numbers = arr => arr.map(Number);
numbers(['1', '2', '3','4']);     // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

The underscore js way -

```js
var a = "1,2,3,4",
  b = a.split(',');

//remove falsy/empty values from array after split
b = _.compact(b);
//then Convert array of string values into Integer
b = _.map(b, Number);

console.log('Log String to Int conversion @b =', b);
```

Answer (score 3):

Matt Zeunert's version with use arraw function (ES6)

```
const nums = a.split(',').map(x => parseInt(x, 10));
```

Comment: what is 10 represent for ??

Answer (score 1):

Since all the answers allow `NaN` to be included, I thought I'd add that if you want to quickly cast an array of mixed values to numbers you can do.

```
var a = "1,2,3,4,foo,bar";

var b = a.split(',');

var result = b.map(_=>_|0) // Floors the number (32-bit signed integer) so this wont work if you need all 64 bits.

// or b.map(_=>_||0) if you know your array is just numbers but may include NaN.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), adding brakets to format ***Array***

```js
const a = "1,2,3,4";
const myArray = JSON.parse(`[${a}]`)
console.log(myArray)
console.info('pos 2 = ',  myArray[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can transform array of strings to array of numbers in one line:

```
const arrayOfNumbers = arrayOfStrings.map(e => +e);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let ar = [ '682',    '874',    '906',    '11168',  '73714',
  '74377',  '74034',  '138860', '138891', '139161', '139562',
  '139733', '139560', '74049',  '139759', '139934', '140104',
  '141335', '141356', '141334', '141337', '141360', '141358',
  '141365', '141419', '143333', '151477', '147342', '141355',
  '167847', '192141', '196760', '191687', '197351', '197055',
  '198852', '198731', '198816', '199034', '200053', '199226',
  '217818', '200055', '222039', '230533', '230530', '231127',
  '222042', '231100', '236171', '236913', '236980', '237015',
  '237016', '237052', '237551', '237560', '237590', '237637',
  '237733', '237731', '237655', '238890', '238910', '238837',
  '238926', '238972', '238925', '239755', '239696', '239898',
  '240037', '239909', '240036', '240082', '240097', '240526',
  '240770', '678151', '678950', '678985'];
let arry=[]
ar.map(arr=>{
arry.push(parseInt(arr))
});

console.log(arry);
```