# replace string with numbers that resembles the string using string.replace()

Tags: javascript

Here I have a line of code which I would prefer to take `'123'` as a string value.
Then with the help of split() and join() it will become a string like `'1,2,3'`.
Then I want to replace all the numeric string values with actual number like `1,2....`.
For this I used a variable called `k` and give it an initial value 1.
I used an increment operator inside replace to change the value of `k`.
But it is not working. Maybe I am getting it wrong how string.replace() execute the replacement operation.
I also tried to use `parseInt('$1')` it also didn't work.

console gives output of 1,1,1.No increment operation takes place.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>

(function(){
var k=1;
   console.log(prompt('input here').split('').join(',').replace(/(\d)/g,k++));
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean you want to convert `"123"` into an array of numbers `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: yes.something like that BUT using a single line of code.

Comment: Could you add examples of input and output as you see it, without describing how you want to get that output from that input? )

Comment: Sounds like a `map` function

Comment: If you don't want to increment the numbers `var arr = '123'.split('').map(Number);` is the simplest solution I know.

Comment: @mplungjan: While using [that approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677869/converting-string-array-to-int-array) you linked and `reduce` (not `map`) might be a better solution, it's not a duplicate imho

Comment: `var a = "123".split('').map(function(item) {
    item = parseInt(item, 10);
    return ++item;
});` works for me

Comment: Or, upon re-reading, is it actually and OP doesn't want to create incrementing numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use replace callback instead:

```
var k = 1;
'123'.split('').join(',').replace(/\d/g, function() {
  return k++;
});
```

As it stands, `k++` *value* is taken as an argument - in other words, this operation is evaluated just once.

But if you want just to get a sequence of integers, there are far better approaches. For example:

```
function getSequence(start, end) {
  var res = [];
  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    res.push(i);
  }
  return res;

  // or just...
  // return Array.apply(0, Array(end - start + 1))
  //             .map(function(_, i) { return start + i });
  // ... if you feel adventurous. )
}
getSequence(2, 4); // [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: You're relieving me from having to write my own answers :-)

Comment: Won't this only work for a string of the form "1234..."? I think the one in OP's post was just an example.

Comment: @JLRishe No, it replaces any digit in the number by the iterated index (leaving the non-digit symbols as they are).

Comment: why we need to add a callback function? i mean why increment operation didn't work directly??

Comment: Because `k++` is just an _expression_, not a _command_. `replace` function will receive the result of this expression as its parameter - it won't have any idea about how you've come with this result.

Comment: as you said "in other words, this operation is evaluated just once"  shouldn't it call the callback function just once and use the value of k for the rest of the operation.It seems confusing a little .i think every one didn't get my question :(

Comment: The _callback_ will be invoked each time a replacement operation is in progress; its return value for the _given_ invokation will be used as a replacement value. That's why it's named `callback`, after all.

Comment: @raina77ow Well, that's my point. If the input string is "498", then the result will still be `1, 2, 3`. I could be mistaken, but I think OP wants `4, 9, 8` in that case.

Comment: @JLRishe Why would he want to do any replacement then?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to increase the numbers:

```
var arr = '123'.split('').map(Number);
```

If you do:

```
var arr = '123'.split('').map(function (num) { return Number(num) + 1; });
```