# Format HERE Map API JSON Response

Tags: json, api, here-api

I am experiencing an issue formatting the JSON response from the HERE Map API for an isoline. The full HERE API JSON response is shown below and contains Lat/Long coordinates for a line as shown below.

```
{
    "response": {
        "metaInfo": {
            "timestamp": "2017-03-03T23:40:34Z",
            "mapVersion": "8.30.68.151",
            "moduleVersion": "7.2.201709-111134",
            "interfaceVersion": "2.6.29"
        },
        "center": {
            "latitude": 34.603565,
            "longitude": -98.3959
        },
        "isoline": [
            {
                "range": 300,
                "component": [
                    {
                        "id": 0,
                        "shape": [
                            "34.6096802,-98.4147549",
                            "34.6096802,-98.4141541",
                            "34.6098518,-98.4136391",
                            "34.6101952,-98.4132957",
                            "34.6103668,-98.4127808",
                            "34.6101952,-98.4122658",
                            "34.6098518,-98.4119225",
                            "34.6098518,-98.4115791",
                            "34.6101952,-98.4112358",
                            "34.5998955,-98.4115791",
                            "34.6002388,-98.4126091",
                            "34.6005821,-98.4129524",
                            "34.6009254,-98.4139824",
                            "34.6019554,-98.4143257",
                            "34.6022987,-98.4153557",
....
                            "34.6081352,-98.4129524",
                            "34.6083069,-98.4134674",
                            "34.6083069,-98.4148407",
                            "34.6084785,-98.4153557",
                            "34.6089935,-98.4155273",
                            "34.6095085,-98.4154415",
                            "34.6096802,-98.415184",
                            "34.6096802,-98.4147549"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "start": {
            "linkId": "+888249498",
            "mappedPosition": {
                "latitude": 34.6034836,
                "longitude": -98.3959009
            },
            "originalPosition": {
                "latitude": 34.603565,
                "longitude": -98.3959
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am mapping the isoline data in Leaflet as a polygon. I can do it manually like this, and all works well.

```
var polygon = L.polygon([
[34.6343994, -98.7664032],
[34.6357727, -98.76297],
[34.6385193, -98.7602234],
[34.6398926, -98.7561035],
[34.6385193, -98.7519836],
[34.6357727, -98.7492371],
[34.6357727, -98.7464905],
.....
[34.6302795, -98.7712097],
[34.6330261, -98.7718964],
[34.6343994, -98.7698364],
[34.6343994, -98.7664032]

]
            ).addTo(map);
```

Am now trying to automate it but cannot get the json output into a compatible format for Leaflet. I can make the API call, capture the JSON response, and extract the array of lat/long coordinates using the following code:

```
    function getJson(url) {
        return JSON.parse($.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: '',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            global: false,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                return data;
            }
        }).responseText);
    }

    var myJsonObj = getJson('https://isoline.route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateisoline.json?mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&jsonAttributes=1&rangetype=time&start=34.603565,-98.3959&app_id=id&app_code=codeg&range=1800');

var isoline = myJsonObj.response.isoline[0].component[0].shape;
```

The variable isoline looks like this (an array of lat/long coordinate pairs) but I cannot get them into an array of arrays as needed for Leaflet.

```
[
                                "34.6096802,-98.4147549",
                                "34.6096802,-98.4141541",
                                "34.6098518,-98.4136391",
                                "34.6101952,-98.4132957",
                                "34.6103668,-98.4127808",
                                "34.6101952,-98.4122658",
                                "34.6098518,-98.4119225",
                                "34.6098518,-98.4115791",
                                "34.6101952,-98.4112358",
                                "34.5998955,-98.4115791",
                                "34.6002388,-98.4126091",
                                "34.6005821,-98.4129524",
                                "34.6009254,-98.4139824",
                                "34.6019554,-98.4143257",
                                "34.6022987,-98.4153557",
    ....
                                "34.6081352,-98.4129524",
                                "34.6083069,-98.4134674",
                                "34.6083069,-98.4148407",
                                "34.6084785,-98.4153557",
                                "34.6089935,-98.4155273",
                                "34.6095085,-98.4154415",
                                "34.6096802,-98.415184",
                                "34.6096802,-98.4147549"
                            ]
```

Would appreciate any help in reformatting the coordinates to look like this

```
[
    [34.6343994, -98.7664032],
    [34.6357727, -98.76297],
    [34.6385193, -98.7602234],
    [34.6398926, -98.7561035],
    [34.6385193, -98.7519836],
    [34.6357727, -98.7492371],
    [34.6357727, -98.7464905],
    .....
    [34.6302795, -98.7712097],
    [34.6330261, -98.7718964],
    [34.6343994, -98.7698364],
    [34.6343994, -98.7664032]

    ]
```

It may be that there is a better way of putting the data in Leaflet as well, but Polygon and Polyline are the only methods I can find and they require the coordinates in an array of arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You need to **iterate** over **each** element and **split**, forming an **array**.

Like this, (ES6 way)

```
const newArray = array.map(a => a.split(',').map(Number));
```

or (Non ES6 way)

```
var newArray = [];
array.forEach(function (a){ newArray.push(a.split(',').map(Number)); });
```

So your final code should look like this,

```
function getJson(url) {
  return JSON.parse($.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: '',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    global: false,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
      return data;
    }
  }).responseText);
}

function parseJSONForPolygon(rawJsonArray) {
  var newArray = [];
  rawJsonArray.forEach(function (a) { newArray.push(a.split(',').map(Number)); });
  return newArray;
};

var myJsonObj = getJson('https://isoline.route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateisoline.json?mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&jsonAttributes=1&rangetype=time&start=34.603565,-98.3959&app_id=id&app_code=codeg&range=1800');

var isoline = parseJSONForPolygon(myJsonObj.response.isoline[0].component[0].shape);
```

*`.map(Number)` credit goes to
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/15677905/923426*

Comment: +1 Thank you! I discovered I needed to remove the double quotes from the lat/long coordinates as well. Any problem with using: isoline = JSON.stringify(isoline).replace(/['"]+/g, '') and then JSON.parse before adding it to Leaflet?

Answer (score 2):

```
let polygonArray = [];

data.response.isoline.component.shape.forEach((elm) => {
  polygonArray.push(elm.split(','));
})
```

now your `polygonArray` will be acceptable by leaflet