# Javascript: How to force .split() to create numArray?

Tags: javascript

This is just an example, I have much more amount of data:

```
var str = "3.0;4.5;5.2;6.6";
var res = str.split(";");
console.log(res);
```

The output will be an array of strings. How can I have array of numbers without going through the existing array again?

Comment: This is an exsisting post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677869/how-to-convert-a-string-of-numbers-to-an-array-of-numbers

Comment: This question is different from both of those questions, because of the *"**without going through the existing array again**"*.

Comment: In 99% of cases people add these restrictions because they mistakenly think that avoiding loops will somehow improve performance, when in fact convoluted solutions without loops are often much worse performancewise.

Answer (score 6):

> ...without going through the existing array again?

That's tricky. You can't with `split`, because `split` produces an array of strings. You could do it in a single pass with a regular expression, building the array yourself:

```js
var rex = /[^;]+/g;
var str = "3.0;4.5;5.2;6.6";
var match;
var res = [];
while ((match = rex.exec(str)) != null) {
  res.push(+match[0]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Or actually, that's more overhead than necessary, just `indexOf` and `substring` will do:

```js
var str = "3.0;4.5;5.2;6.6";
var start = 0, end;
var res = [];
while ((end = str.indexOf(";", start)) !== -1) {
  res.push(+str.substring(start, end));
  start = end + 1;
}
if (start < str.length) {
  res.push(+str.substring(start));
}
console.log(res);
```

[KooiInc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53778386/157247) uses `replace` to do the loop for us, which is clever.

---

**That said**, unless you have a truly ***massive*** array, going through the array again is simpler:

```
var res = str.split(";").map(entry => +entry);
```

---

In the above, I convert from string to number using a unary `+`. That's only one of many ways, and they have pros and cons. I do a rundown of the options in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875).

Comment: *(Doh! If you see an over-complicated regex above, hit refresh. Clearly need more tea this morning...)*

Comment: `while ((match = rex.exec(str))` => well, you're not going trough the existing `Array`, I'll give you that, but aren't you just going trough a new `Array` (of matches)? Maybe look at _transducers_ (https://medium.com/javascript-scene/transducers-efficient-data-processing-pipelines-in-javascript-7985330fe73d)?

Comment: @KooiInc - Not *going through* a new array, no. Creating, accessing an entry from, and throwing away, yes. Which is one of the reasons for my *"...unless you have a truly massive array, going through the array again is simpler:..."* :-) You could, of course, do it without a regular expression, too.

Comment: @KooiInc - Added a non-regex version. No need for regex here.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `map()`:

```js
var str = "3.0;4.5;5.2;6.6";
var res = str.split(";").map(Number);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @C4mps - Probably because the OP specifically said *"... **without going through the existing array again**"*. This does exactly what the OP said they didn't want to do. Otherwise, the question would be a duplicate of about 50 other questions.

Comment: If you want to convert, or more simply get data from an array, you'll always have to go through it... I cannot see a more simple solution than this one. It does exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: @C4mps - No, again, it does exactly what the OP said they **didn't** want. You can absolutely convert the numbers in that string to an array of numbers in a single pass. See Nick Parson's answer (although it does make two passes through the *data*, just not an array), or mine (truly single pass).

Comment: Yes, I like your solution. My point was that the .map function does the job in one single pass :) so using .map function is the best solution in this case.

Comment: @C4mps - Please read the question carefully. It's clear the OP wants to make a **single** pass through the data, not **two passes**. This answer makes **two passes**: `split` and `map`. (In fact, Nick Parson's answer is two-pass as well, I shouldn't have mentioned it above.) And again, if `map` were the answer, then answering is pointless: Instead, VTC as a duplicate of any of the many existing questions without the OP's restriction.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. I up voted your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could replace all the `;` using regex with `,` and then use `JSON.parse()` to convert it to an array of numbers:

```js
var str = "3;4;5;6".replace(/;/g, ',');
var res = JSON.parse("["+str+"]");
console.log(res);
```

Do note though, in terms of its efficiency, this isn't any better than using a simple `.map` to go through the array again.

Comment: not sure if OP wanted something effecient or just another way of doing this. Pretty sure this doesn't count as being efficient

Comment: To be fair, this is still two passes through the **data** (one for `replace`, another for `parse`). But it does technically not go through the *array* twice.

Comment: ah, yeah *technically*, so not any better than using map I suppose

Answer (score 2):

Another idea without `split`:

```js
const str2Numbers = (str, numbers = []) => 
 str.replace(/[^;]+/g, a => numbers.push(+a)) && numbers;
console.log(str2Numbers("3.0;4.5;5.2;6.6;3421"));
```

Comment: **Nice**, using `replace` to do the loop. That was floating around the back of my mind at one point and for some reason didn't land. You don't need the capture group (you aren't using it) or the `&& a`, and the regex can be simpler (in case there are numbers like `32;.1`: `const str2Numbers = (str, numbers = []) => str.replace(/[^;]+/g, a => numbers.push(+a)) && numbers;`

Comment: Thnx @T.J.Crowder, edited. I think I also needed more ... well ... _coffee_, in my case ;)

Answer (score -2):

That's tricky. You can't with split, because split produces an array of strings.

```
var str = "3.0;4.5;5.2;6.6";
var res = str.split(',').map(function(number) {
    console.log(res);
    return parseInt(number, 10);    
});
```

Comment: What's the purpose of copying the opening line of my answer, followed by the same (incorrect) solution Mamun posted 20 minutes earlier, which does exactly what the OP said they didn't want to do and doesn't relate in any way to the part of my answer you copied?