# How to add multiple elements into an Array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to take an input from a text file (for example 3 7 9 53 2) and place those values into an array.

3 7 9 53 2

I tried with prompt(), but I obviously can only add them one by one:

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    Array[i] = parseInt(prompt("Value for Array"));
}
```

However, I want to read line by line and add them to an array. A line will contain hundreds of numbers. is there a way to fill an array quickly by copying and pasting the data into the console? Like in java

```
String[] line = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
```

Comment: why not write the data into a file?

Comment: Your desired output seems all over the place... prompt, console, text file..

Comment: You can read from the text file directly. See if this is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file

Comment: This might help, prompt() is also used there and the string is split by comma which you could change to a space .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60365578/pushing-new-comma-separated-string-of-numbers-to-an-existing-array/60365636#60365636

Comment: Can you explain to us how are you reading the file?

Answer (score 3):

First use the split function to transform your string into array, then for each element of your array convert it into a number, Then you are done :)

```js
var c = "12 2 23 3 4"
var res = c.split(" ")
for (var i=0; i < res.length; i++) {
  res[i] = parseInt(res[i])
}
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume let result=[], so you want to add string in an array which can be directly assigned as "result=c.split(" ")" in case result is empty but if you want to assign multiple strings to the same array you can refer code.

````
var c = "12 2 23 3 4"
let d=" 1 2 3 4 5 6"
if(result.length === 0){
  result = c.split(" ")
}else{
 let tempArray = d.split(" ")
result.push(...tempArray)
}
console.log(result)```
````

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with an inliner `.split(" ")` and `.map(Number)`

The first one will split the string by spaces, creating an array of each word/number, the second one will loop this array and convert every word to number, see below

```js
let data = "3 7 9 53 2"
let array = data.split(" ").map(Number)

console.log(array)
```

Comment: functionnal programming is very nice