# How to convert a string representation to an array integers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, parsing, numbers

How to convert a single string element representing an array of integers as strings to an array of integers in Javascript?

I have a string like this

```
var str = "["163600", "163601", "166881"]";
```

My output should be

```
[163600, 163601, 166881]
```

What I am trying is

```
var myArr = JSON.parse(str)
```

but in result I am getting an array of strings.

```
["163600", "163601", "166881"]
```

How can I get an array of integers?

I am trying to further parse like this

`parseInt(myArr)` but this is giving only for `0th` index. Is there any way to get for the whole array?

Comment: This `"["here!` is already an invalid string. PS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58833088/383904

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easy way is using [**`.map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array along with using [**`Number`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) to parse each string into numbers.

```js
var str = ["163600", "163601", "166881"];
var result = str.map(Number);
console.log(result);

/*Using `JSON.parse` first if your data is not an string array.*/
console.log(JSON.parse("[\"163600\", \"163601\", \"166881\"]").map(Number));
```

---

**More detailed explanation**

> The `map()` method **creates a new array** populated with the results of
> calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

> When used as a function, `Number(value) converts a string or other value to the Number type`. If the value can't be converted, it returns
> NaN.

Answer (score 4):

Try using [map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp):

```js
var string = "[\"163600\", \"163601\", \"166881\"]";
var result = JSON.parse(string).map(function(number){ return parseInt(number, 10) || number; });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: [Always use a radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#description) - just for muscle memory if nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const result = strings.map(el => parseInt(el));
```

`Number` function will work too. Don't include curly braces in the callback.

Comment: [Always use a radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#description) - just for muscle memory if nothing else. ParseInt does not defaults to base10.

Answer (score 1):

Use `+` operator to convert to Number

```js
var str = "[\"163600\", \"163601\", \"166881\"]";

const res = JSON.parse(str).map(item => +item);

console.log(res)
```