# Convert string of numbers to array of numbers?

Tags: javascript

I have a string of numbers

```
let numbers = ["54321"]
```

I want to turn it into

```
let numbersToArray = [5,4,3,2,1]
```

I've tried split, push and other ways to but seem to crack it

Comment: Show what you tried so we can help you understand where you went wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a string of numbers to an array of numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677869/how-to-convert-a-string-of-numbers-to-an-array-of-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let numbers = ["54321"]
const temp = numbers[0].split('')
const result = temp.map(n =>  parseInt(n))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: why only `numbers[0]`

Comment: Hey mate :), because it's first element of numbers array

Comment: My question is why wont you consider rest of the numbers from the array

Comment: Because there is only one element in question

Comment: So you will change the code if the requirement changes to consider all the elements of the array ?

Comment: Or i will use your answer :)) Just kidding mate, sure you are right , then i will need another solution

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using a normal for loop and while. Iterate through the length of `numbers` array and while the length of the string is greater than 0 push the push character of the string to another array. Before pushing convert the character to number and then remove the character from the string

```js
let numbers = ["54321", '2'];
let data = [];

for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  let num = numbers[i];
  while (num.length > 0) {
    data.push(parseInt(num.charAt(0)));
    num = num.substr(1)
  }
};
console.log(data)
```

A slight modification of the above can be done by first joining the all strings of the array. Then you can avoid the outer for-loop

```js
let numbers = ["54321", '2'];
let data = [];
let newNum = numbers.join('');
while (newNum.length > 0) {
  data.push(parseInt(newNum.charAt(0)));
  newNum = newNum.substr(1)
};
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) along with [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split into individual characters and map the splitted items back to numbers again.

```js
const numbers = ['54321', '09876'];

const mapped = numbers.reduce((r, c) => {
    r.push(...c.split('').map(Number));
    return r;
}, []);

console.log(mapped);
```